# (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

> (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
> (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

```cs
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("headless"); // headless -> no browser window. needed for jenkins
options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("www.google.com")`
```

Comment: Which version of Google Chrome and ChromeDriver are you using? Can you [edit] your question to include the command line or standard output?